# Arduino Due Serial Config

Tags: arduino

I had been using `Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8E1)` in Arduino Mega without problem. When I changed to Arduino Due, I got this error: `'SERIAL_8E1' was not declared in this scope`. Apparently, there is a different way of declaring the serial config, any help?

Answer (score 0):

`SERIAL_8E1` is defined with

```
#define SERIAL_8E1 0x26
```

So this should work:

```
Serial.begin(9600, 0x26);
```

This works, too:

```
Serial.begin(9600, 38);
```

Comment: The PLC that I am communicating with Due is fixed with 8E1. If I drop the SERIAL_8E1 part of the serial config, Due will be having default 8N1.

Comment: @LowLeeJoo Okay, I completely changed my answer.